# unstable_getServerSession to secure apis (nextAuth)

Tags: next-auth

i need to secure the API so that only authorized user can access them. I followed the documentation in this link https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#securing-api-routes but apparently I am not retrieving the session.
I am able to console.log the authOptions but if I try to console log the session (and I am logged in), it logs "null"
This is the code

pages/api/profile.js

```
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const session = await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
  console.log("SESSION", session); // this logs "null"
  if (!session) {
    return res.status(401).json("Not authorized");
  }
 try {
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { email: session.user.email },
      });
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return res
        .status(503)
        .json(
          "Our server is not able to process the request at the moment, please try again later!"
        );
    }
```

pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CognitoProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito";
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENTID_NEXTAUTH,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENTSECRET_NEXTAUTH,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",

    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,

    updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60,
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: { email: session?.user?.email },
      });

      if (!user) throw new Error("User not found in the database.");

      const mySession = {
        ...session,
        accessToken: token.accessToken,       
        email: user.email,
      };
      return mySession;
    },
  },
  
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

pages/dashboard/index.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getSession, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

const Dashboard = (props) => {
    let { data: session, status } = useSession();

    if (status === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <p>
     {props.userInfo.name}
    </p>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  console.log("SESSION IN INDEX", session); // this logs the session
  const userInfo = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/profile?email=${session.email}`
  );
  

  return {
    props: {
      session,
      userInfo: userInfo.data ? userInfo.data : null,     
    },
  };
}
```

so when I login, I can see the SESSION in INDEX but when I hit the api/profile, the session from unstable_getServerSession is null, so I canno see nothing in the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

resolved:

when calling the api you need to pass the headers, for example in the dashboard/index.js

```
const userInfo = await axios.get(
    `${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/profiles/profile?email=${session.email}`,
    {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie,
      },
    }
  );
```

while in the API endpoint

```
import { getServerSession, getSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handler(req, res) {  
  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);  
  console.log("SESSION", session);
  //your code
}
```